# Не получается соединить строки

Tags: mysql, c++-cli

`String^ param = System::Convert::ToString(comboBox1->SelectedItem);

String^ q = "select * from telekanal.channel where channel.title =";
    MySqlCommand^ query = gcnew MySqlCommand(q + param,connect);`

При выполнение ругается на кавычки в конце в пр. q

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySql server version for the right syntax to use near " at line 1

Comment: 1) Что в `param` ? Выведите получившуюся строку (`q+param`), наверняка она некорректная - `param` не заключён в кавычки  2) используйте placeholders и забудьте про формирование строк для запросов напрямую.

Comment: @pinktux поправил

Comment: что поправил? Не вижу содержимого param, и не вижу как эта строка в кавычки заключается. То есть получиться должно: `where channel.title="foo"`. А у вас наверняка этих кавычек нет: `where channel.title=`foo`.